# Mock setup for Marten.IDocumentSession (Moq/Nunit)

Tags: c#, nunit, moq, marten

I am trying to mock this statement:

```
IReadOnlyList<Student> students = await _session
    .Query<Student>()
    .Where(x => x.ClassId == classId)
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

My attempt at is:

```
private Mock<IDocumentSession> _sessionMock = new Mock<IDocumentSession>();
...
_sessionMock
    .Setup(x => x
        .Query<Students>()
        .Where(y => y.ClassId == classId)
        .ToListAsync(CancellationToken.None))
    .ReturnsAsync(new List<Students));
```

But i am getting this error:

> System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: ... => ....ToListAsync(CancellationToken.None)
> Extension methods (here: QueryableExtensions.ToListAsync) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

I looked it up and read the answers I am getting from SOF and other places and understood that basically it's not easily possible to test extension methods.

The answers are old, like 5+ years, some from 2011, since then is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: I did not find any working solution to be able to mock `IMartenQueryable`

---

The `IDocumentSession` interface has the following inheritance chain:

```
IDocumentSession << IDocumentOperations << IQuerySession
```

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/JasperFx/marten/blob/64598221e07050a8d1d82ef855011994e094260a/src/Marten/IQuerySession.cs) the `Query` method is defined on `IQuerySession` interface like this

```
/// <summary>
///     Use Linq operators to query the documents
///     stored in Postgresql
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <returns></returns>
IMartenQueryable<T> Query<T>();
```

The [`IMartenQueryable<T>`](https://github.com/JasperFx/marten/blob/b77d5537327d5e69710cceafc90bd2fb43c3e49f/src/Marten/Linq/IMartenQueryable.cs#L47) is indeed an `IQueryable<T>`.

And that could be easily mocked via the [MockQueryable.Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MockQueryable.Moq).

```
List<Student> students = ...
var queryableMock = students.BuildMock();
_sessionMock.Setup(x => x.Query<Student>()).Returns(queryableMock);
```

---

I haven't tested the code, maybe you have to cast it to `IMartenQueryable`.

---

**UPDATE #1**

Based on this [`QueryableExtensions`](https://github.com/JasperFx/marten/blob/b77d5537327d5e69710cceafc90bd2fb43c3e49f/src/Marten/QueryableExtensions.cs) we should be able to convert `IQueryable<Student>` to `IMartenQueryable<Student>` via the `As` operator.

The `As` defined inside the `JasperFx.Core.Reflection` namespace.

I've created to convert

```
var queryableMock = students.AsQueryable().As<IMartenQueryable<Student>>();
//OR
var queryableMock = students.BuildMock().As<IMartenQueryable<Student>>();
```

but unfortunately it fails with `InvalidCastException`.

Tomorrow I'll continue my investigation from here.

---

**UPDATE #2**

As it turned out the `As<T>` function is just a simple wrapper around type cast... So, it did not help anything.

I've also tried to mock directly the `IMartenQueryable<T>` and it's `ToListAsync` member method. The problem with this approach is that you need to rewrite your production query to filter elements in memory << kills to whole point of having an `IQueryable<T>` (or a derived interface).

So, I gave up, I don't have any idea, how to do it properly. But as I have seen in the documentation and in the issues we are not the only ones :D

Comment: Casting does not seem to work `query as IMartenQueryable<xxxx>` just returns null.

Comment: @AdilH.Raza Let me test it on my local machine. I'll shortly update the post.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at it

Comment: @AdilH.Raza I give up, I did not find any working solution. So, I will delete my post.

Comment: There's no need to delete the answer, someone else in the future could take it from here and make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I deatl with it by creating class `MartenQueryableStub`:

```cs
internal class MartenQueryableStub<T> : List<T>, IMartenQueryable<T>
{
    private readonly Mock<IQueryProvider> queryProviderMock = new();
    public Type ElementType => typeof(T);

    public Expression Expression => Expression.Constant(this);

    public IQueryProvider Provider
    {
        get
        {
            queryProviderMock
                .Setup(x => x.CreateQuery<T>(It.IsAny<Expression>()))
                .Returns(this);
            return queryProviderMock.Object;
        }
    }

    public QueryStatistics Statistics => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public Task<bool> AnyAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<double> AverageAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<int> CountAsync(CancellationToken token) 
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<long> CountLongAsync(CancellationToken token) 
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public QueryPlan Explain(FetchType fetchType = FetchType.FetchMany, Action<IConfigureExplainExpressions>? configureExplain = null)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<TResult> FirstAsync<TResult>(CancellationToken token)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<TResult?> FirstOrDefaultAsync<TResult>(CancellationToken token)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IMartenQueryable<T> Include<TInclude>(Expression<Func<T, object>> idSource, Action<TInclude> callback) where TInclude : notnull
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IMartenQueryable<T> Include<TInclude>(Expression<Func<T, object>> idSource, IList<TInclude> list) where TInclude : notnull
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IMartenQueryable<T> Include<TInclude, TKey>(Expression<Func<T, object>> idSource, IDictionary<TKey, TInclude> dictionary)
        where TInclude : notnull
        where TKey : notnull
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<TResult> MaxAsync<TResult>(CancellationToken token)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<TResult> MinAsync<TResult>(CancellationToken token)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<TResult> SingleAsync<TResult>(CancellationToken token)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<TResult?> SingleOrDefaultAsync<TResult>(CancellationToken token)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IMartenQueryable<T> Stats(out QueryStatistics stats)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<TResult> SumAsync<TResult>(CancellationToken token)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IAsyncEnumerable<T> ToAsyncEnumerable(CancellationToken token = default)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<IReadOnlyList<TResult>> ToListAsync<TResult>(CancellationToken token) =>
        Task.FromResult(this.ToList().AsReadOnly().As<IReadOnlyList<TResult>>());
```

And then I set up method (in my case `QueryRawEventDataOnly<T>()`)

```cs
var myEntites = new MartenQueryableStub<MyType>() {
    myFirstEntity,
    mySecondEntity,
    ...
    myLastEntity

};
eventStoreMock.Setup(v => v.QueryRawEventDataOnly<MyType>())
    .Returns(myEntites);
```

In your case it shoud be something like that

```cs
var students = new MartenQueryableStub<Student>() {
    student1,
    student2,
    student3,
    ...
};
_sessionMock.Setup(v => v.Query<Student>())
    .Returns(students);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**